# Can't access localhost sites anymore

Tags: iis, localhost

**No access to localhost sites anymore.**

I have IIS 6.0 running on a Windows 7 64 bit PC where I work on local websites.

I have 4 sites that were working until yesterday and now give me a 404 error when I try to access. I have tried IE, Chrome, Brave and Firefox.

One of the sites I'm working on for our karate club is a login for weekend courses where the member's card is checked by a webcam in a box to allow them to log in. It was working (they all were), but I needed this site to be HTTPS as the javascripts for the camera must be downloaded using this protocol. The location of the course may not have internet access so these must be loaded from the localhost site.

I was messing about trying creating self signed certificates for localhost which I managed to do, but i could not get the site to work using https. I then removed the certificates but the sites would not then access normally (http).

I cleared the cache of each browser and have reset IIS and restarted the pc. I also went through and disabled the world wide services, restarted the PC and restarted WWS.

Nothing has helped.

Any advice/pointers would be a great help.

Thanks in Advance,

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself by doing a system restore to the point just before i installed the IIS toolkit. My sites are now back to working using http again.

I'm guessing that it was something in the toolkit that caused the problem.

Thanks for the advice anyway.

Regards,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what changes you made that caused problems with your site. If your website requires HTTPS, you need to obtain a certificate from a trusted certificate authority (CA) instead of using a self-signed certificate to ensure you have a valid SSL certificate.

According to your description, after you delete the certificate, the website cannot be accessed normally through http. You need to check your website configuration in IIS to make sure that your website's bindings are configured correctly. And you can remove the HTTPS binding for your sites and see if you can access them using HTTP. Also, you can check the IIS logs for any detailed error messages that might be the cause of the 404.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I didn't think I needed a Trusted CA and only needed a self signed one as it will only be used with localhost. As I said, I can't guarantee that the location of the courses will have internet access so it has to work local only.  Bindings are all for http on port 80 only now. Where can I find the IIS log files ?